# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'long'

Tags: python, numpy

I am clustering the data into two clusters then I am going to calculate the mean vector but I got the following error.  However, when I change [3,7] to [3,1], the problem will be solved!!! anyone can help me? Thank you in advance

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ao.py", line 36, in <module>
    (r,d,u)=update(clusters)
  File "ao.py", line 30, in update
    c=np.mean(d, axis=0)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2716, in
mean
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 69, in _mean

    ret = ret / rcount
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'long'
```

---

```
import numpy as np
clusters = {}
X = np.array([[1,1],[1.5,2],[3,4],[5,7],[3.5,5],[3,7],[3.5,4.5],[5,8],[5,1],[2,3]])
centroid = ([[2.6,2],[4,6.3]])

def a(X):  
    for x in X:     
        z= min([(i[0], np.linalg.norm(x-centroid[i[0]]))  for i in enumerate(centroid)], key=lambda t:t[1])

        try:
            clusters[z].append(x)
        except KeyError:
            clusters[z]=[x]
    return clusters

def update (clusters):
    d=[]
    r=[]
    c=[]
    keys = sorted(clusters.keys())
    for k in keys:
        if k[0]==0:
            r.append(clusters[(k[0],k[1])])       
        else:
            d.append(clusters[(k[0],k[1])])

    c=np.mean(d, axis=0)
    u=np.mean(r,axis=0) 
    return(u,c)


clusters=a(X)
(u,c)=update(clusters)

print "c:",c
print "u:",u
```

Comment: as the error says, `ret` or `rcount` is a list.

Comment: `numpy.mean` expects an array. You gave it a list.

Comment: ok, but why when  I change [3,7] to [3,1] in X, I got no error and it calculates the mean

Comment: I think that the problem is that the list `[3,7]` results in an empty `d` list. Could you maybe check that?

Answer (score 5):

`np.mean` does work with arrays represented as lists, for example:

```
np.mean([[1],[4],[6]])
```

However it doesn't work with arrays that do not have a regular shape, e.g.:

```
np.mean([[1, 2],[4],[6]])
```

That's the problem that you have, because variable `d` inside function `a` looks like:

```
[[array([ 5. ,  7. ]), array([ 3.,  7.])],
 [array([ 3.5,  5. ])                   ],
 [array([ 3.5,  4.5])                   ],
 [array([ 5. ,  8. ])                   ]]
```

I think you need to find a better way to organize your data.

Comment: the problem is related to variable d

Comment: before calculating the mean vector, the r & d are like: r: [[array([ 2., 3.])], [array([ 1.5, 2. ])], [array([ 3., 4.])], [array([ 1. , 1.])], [array([ 5., 1.])]] d: [[array([ 5., 7.]), array([ 3., 7.])], [array([ 3.5, 5. ])], [array([ 3.5, 4.5])], [array([ 5., 8.])]] ----- the program is calculating the np.mean (r,axi=0) without error. So, the problem is related to d

Comment: @user3616059: Yes that's what I'm saying: the array `d` is not rectangular and that causes the error.